# Misplaced supertabular at the bottom of a page

Tags: spacing, positioning, supertabular

I want to write a table which is too long to fit in the middle of a page. So I thought of using `supertabular`. My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\tablefirsthead{\hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{$\mathbf{^{210}Po/V_{drift}=800V}$} &     \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{$\mathbf{^{55}Fe/V_{drift}=800V}$}\\
    \hline}

\tablehead{%
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|r|}{next page $...$ } \\
\hline
}
\tabletail{%
\hline   
\multicolumn{6}{|r|}{next page $...$ } \\
\hline
}
\tablelasttail{
\hline
}
\bottomcaption{electron  transparency}
    \label{tab:mm3trans}
\begin{supertabular}[H]{|C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{1cm}||C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{1cm}|}
%       \hline
%       \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{$\mathbf{^{210}Po/V_{drift}=800V}$} & \multicolumn{3}    {|c|}{$\mathbf{^{55}Fe/V_{drift}=800V}$}\\
%       \hline
        $V_{mesh}$ \newline ($V$) & Centroid & Gain & $V_{mesh}$ \newline ($V$) & Centroid & Gain \newline ($10^3$)\\
        \hline
        ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$& ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$  \\
        \hline
        $500$ & $30$ & $220$ & $560$ & $22$ & $1.06$ \\
        \hline
    $535$ & $67$ & $490$ & $565$ & $25$ & $1.20$ \\
    \hline
    $540$ & $76$ & $556$ & $570$ & $29$ & $1.39$ \\
    \hline
    $545$ & $85$ & $622$ & $575$ & $33$ & $1.58$ \\
    \hline
    $550$ & $97$ & $710$ & $580$ & $38$ & $1.82$ \\
    \hline
    $555$ & $103$ & $754$ & $585$ & $43$ & $2.06$ \\
    \hline
    $560$ & $116$ & $849$ & $590$ & $48$ & $2.30$ \\
    \hline
    $565$ & $131$ & $959$ & $595$ & $56$ & $2.69$ \\
    \hline
    $570$ & $150$ & $1098$ & $600$ & $63$ & $3.02$ \\
    \hline
    $-$ &   $-$ &   $-$ &     $605$ & $72$ & $3.46$ \\
    \hline
    $-$ &   $-$ &   $-$ &     $610$ & $83$ & $3.98$ \\
    \hline
$-$ &   $-$ & $-$ &     $615$ & $94$ & $4.51$ \\
    \hline
    $-$ &   $-$ & $-$ &     $620$ & $106$ & $5.09$ \\
    \hline
    $-$ &   $-$ & $-$ &     $625$ & $122$ & $5.86$ \\
    \hline
    $-$ &   $-$ & $-$ &     $630$ & $138$ & $6.62$ \\
    \hline
    $-$ &   $-$ & $-$ &     $635$ & $156$ & $7.49$ \\
    \hline
    $-$ &   $-$ & $-$ &     $640$ & $180$ & $8.64$ \\
    \hline
    $-$ &   $-$ & $-$ &     $645$ & $204$ & $9.79$ \\
    \hline
    $-$ &   $-$ & $-$ &     $650$ & $235$ & $11.3$ \\
    \hline
    $-$ &   $-$ & $-$ &     $655$ & $263$ & $12.6$ \\
    \hline
    \end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

What is disturbing is that a have a page which is half-full. So I want to add this table in the middle of page. Unfortunately the table is printed on the next page, where it splits at some point and it continues on the next page.

[image]

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Not sure if `supertabular` can start mid page. If you switch to use `longtable` instead then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

After compilation of your original file I had over thirty errors. After small changes, e.g.

```
%\begin{supertabular}[H]{|C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{1cm}||C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{1cm}|}
\begin{supertabular}[H]{|r|r|r||c|c|c|}
```

or

```
%\begin{supertabular}[H]{|C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{1cm}||C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{1cm}|}
\begin{supertabular}[H]{|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{1cm}||p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{1cm}|}
```

all works fine, giving two tables on the page. (Certainly with some differences in the tables.)